# Can a custom action be saved with the PSD document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, actions

I want to send a PSD file of a webpage to the developer to show him some functions. I created actions of some pop-ups opening, but I can't find any information on how to save the actions with the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't save it in the same PSD, but you can provide a separate Actions file. To do so create a new Action set, then place the Action(s) inside it. You'll then be able to use `Save Actions` from the flyout menu to save an Actions file with just the Action(s) you want to send to your developer.